# Celery weighted tasks

Tags: python, concurrency, celery

I wonder if it's possible to add a "weight" to celery task. Here's a concrete example :
I have a GPU with 8Gb of VRAM.
I have three task :

- task1 taking 2Gb
- task2 taking 4Gb
- task3 taking 8Gb

I launch a celery worker with 4 concurrency.

I launch 5 task1, 2 task2 and one task3.

First, i have [task1, task1, task1, task1]. Then, when this task ended, i have [task1, task2], and [task2,task2]. Finally, task3 came when everyone has done.

It is possible to do something like that ? task3 taking 4 slots, task2 taking 2 slots ?

Comment: The closest thing to what you are asking for is implementing a custom Autoscaler which scales up/down number of worker processes depending on the RAM utilisation. It is actually fairly trivial thing to do believe it or not!

Answer (score 0):

Celery isn't going to do this management for you, but you can create your own "leasing" by using shared memory and locks, . If you are using the multiprocessing worker model, look at [the multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) which gives you sufficient primitive tools to manage this yourself. You can do the same with threading or greenlets, but using different concurrency primitives.

A few pointers:

- Set `CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER` to `1` to improve distribution.
- Use the retry mechanism if a task can't be completed due to insufficient resources (giving other tasks which might fit an opportunity to run).
- Don't forget to return leased resources when services error or exit ungracefully.